# Please help me with this Inequalities concept.

Tags: inequality

A few days ago, when I was attending an inequalities class, my teacher explained,
If, $\frac{(x-1)^3}{(x-1)^2}> 0  \implies   (x-1)>0$

Then $x$ is not equal to $1$,

and he explained that, this is true because $0×2=0×5$, but we can't cancel out the zeroes as $2$ is not equal to $5$

I didn't understand his reasoning,
Could you you please
explain the reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever his reasoning might be, the solution to an inequality is subordinated to existence of the algebraic terms that are involved (id est, $x$ must be in the domain of all the function that appear in the expression). Since the division function $(t,s)\mapsto \frac ts$ is defined on $\Bbb R\times (\Bbb R\setminus\{0\})$, id est on the pair of real numbers $(t,s)$ such that $s\ne 0$, $(x-1)^2\ne 0$ is a necessary condition for the inequality to hold.

Comment: please do elaborate in simple terms,

Comment: @AustinRojers This is a mix of plain English and high-school terminology, therefore it classifies as simple terms to me.

Comment: Gae. S.'s point is that the expression doesn't make sense if $x-1=0$ (and thus $x=1$), because of division by $0$ and all that.

Comment: And it seems like (mabe?) your teacher was trying to give some intuition of why division by $0$ is problematic. Perhaps the conclusion is that $x-1\neq 0$, rather than $x-1>0$?

Comment: Thanks that makes some sense